# HightCharts Realtime line error

Tags: highcharts, real-time

[HightCharts realtime line error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cvbey.png)

Who had the following problems?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you were doing and what exactly the error is

Comment: Could you give more specific information about your problem and post live example so we can investigate the issue?

Comment: Sorry for my form of questions.I was the first time in question here.Several days ago,I follow the example of the official website to achieve a real-time line chart, and I refer the link `<script src="http://cdn.hcharts.cn/highcharts/highcharts.js"></script>`,but yestoday when I run  the page,I found a problem in FireFox,as blow photo.Later,I found the highchart's version vary,the above link is v4.2.6, v4.2.5 is correct.  [photo](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Cvbey.png).

Comment: By the code, we mean a JSON with data and chart configuration, which you use.

Answer (score 0):

```
var loadChart = function () {
        $.getJSON('data.json', function (json) {
            var index = 0;

            var getData = function (index, type) {
                var result = null;
                if (type != undefined) {
                    result = parseInt(json[index][type]);
                } else {
                    result = json[index];
                }
                return result;
            };

            var getSeriesData = function () {
                // 结构
                var JJData = [],
                    PCData = [],
                    PhoneData = [],
                    item;
                var time = (new Date()).getTime();

                for (var i = -179; i <= 0; ++i) {
                    item = json[index++];
                    JJData.push({
                        x: time + i * 2000,
                        y: parseInt(item.JJ)
                    });
                    PCData.push({
                        x: time + i * 2000,
                        y: parseInt(item.PC)
                    });
                    PhoneData.push({
                        x: time + i * 2000,
                        y: parseInt(item.Phone)
                    });
                }
                var result = [{
                    name: "JJ",
                    data: JJData
                }, {
                    name: "PC",
                    data: PCData
                }, {
                    name: "Phone",
                    data: PhoneData
                }];
                return result;
            };

            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container1',
                    type: 'spline', //spline
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(202, 202, 202, 0.2)',
                    animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                    //marginRight: 10,
                    events: {
                        load: function () {
                            var series = this.series;

                            loadMinuteData = function () {
                                if (!minuteFlag) {
                                    clearInterval(setMinuteInter);

                                    return false;
                                }
                                var x = (new Date()).getTime(); // current time
                                var result = getData(index++);
                                // 第三个参数为true,移除最开始的数据
                                //console.log("minute");
                                //console.log(series[0]);
                                //alert(series[0]);
                                series[0].addPoint([x, parseInt(result.JJ)], true, true);
                                series[1].addPoint([x, parseInt(result.PC)], true, true);
                                series[2].addPoint([x, parseInt(result.Phone)], true, true);
                            };
                            var setMinuteInter = setInterval(loadMinuteData, 2000);
                        }
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: '实时在线人数'
                },
                xAxis: [{
                    type: 'datetime',
                    tickPixelInterval: 60
                }],
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: '人数'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    spline: {
                        marker: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                            Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                            Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                exporting: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                series: getSeriesData()
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: This is my chart configuration.

Comment: How your data does it look like ? Unfortunately we do not have an information what your function getSeriesData() returns and which values do you add by addPoint(). Could you hardcode values to introduce the issue?

Comment: Hi Eliza, Thank you for providing us your code. It would be great if you are able to give us the hardcoded values to show us exactly what the issue is - just like Sebastian have written. For now I think that your problem is connected with addPoint method inside your load event function. You are redrawing your chart every time you are adding point to any of your series. That may cause some problems if you are redrawing your chart to quick. Try to not redraw your chart on every addPoint, but with chart.redraw(). Look at this example to see how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/hzww145d/3/